# Select input value in a form to be posted in another form

Tags: jquery, html

I want to copy the value of 2nd input in the first form to the second form. multiple forms exists, therefore I can't use id to select form nor input id. The second form is fixed I have no issues with using the id"user1".

```js
$(".copy").on("click", function() {
  var user = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form").last("input").val();
  document.getElementById("user1").setAttribute('value', user);
});
```

```html
<div class="card0">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <input name="age" id="age" value="XXX" type="hidden">
      <input name="user" id="user0" value="XXX" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-success copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card1">
  <form>
    <input name="user" id="user1" value="" type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) right. You need to use it like this:

```
var foo = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form input").last();
```

Working sample:

```js
$(".copy").on("click", function() {
  var user = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form input").last().val();
  document.getElementById("user1").setAttribute('value', user);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card0">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form>
      <input name="age" id="age" value="XXX" type="hidden">
      <input name="user" id="user0" value="XXX" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-success copy">Copy</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card1">
  <form>
    <input name="user" id="user1" value="" type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```